# TextMate suddenly showing <CR> tag in code files

Tags: textmate, textmate2

I have been using TextMate version 2 for MAC from quite some time now, but suddenly yesterday in my code files I am seeing a `<CR>` tag.

Not sure what the issue is. After doing some googling around I found that it is supposed to be a INVISIBLE character.

But now how do I remove it, can any one suggest any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Textmate files are set with one of three options..

- `CR`(e.g. Carriage Return or `\r`) line endings.
- `LF` (e.g. Line Feed or `\n`)
- `CRLF` (e.g. Carriage Return Line Feed or `\r\n`)

If a file has inconsistent line endings, Textmate will treat `\n` as a line ending marker and display `<CR>` as text.

---

The issue is caused by a corrupt Launch Services database and can be fixed by running the following command in Terminal and resetting Finder.

```
sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -kill -r -domain local -domain system -domain user && killall Finder
```

---

```
lsregister: [OPTIONS] [-domain { system | local | user | network }]... [path]...
Search the paths for application bundles and add each found item to the Launch
Services database.  For domain specifications, ask CF for the list of application
locations in the given domain(s).

  -kill     Reset the global Launch Services database before doing anything else
  -lint     Print information about plist errors while registering bundles
  -convert  Register apps found in older LS database files
  -load     Load the LaunchServices service plugin if it's not already loaded.
  -lazy n   Sleep for n seconds before registering apps if the local cache
            is aleady populated.
  -r        Recursively register directory contents, do not recurse into
            packages or invisible directories.
  -R        Recursively register directory contents, including the contents
            of packages and invisible directories.
  -f        force-update registration info even if mod date is unchanged
  -v        Display progress information.
  -dump     Display full database contents after registration.
  -h        Display this help.
```

Comment: do i replace `user` with my username?

Comment: thank you but it didnt work on `TextMate version 2.0-beta.7.1`

Comment: Wow.  I am new to TextMate, but this is a killer.  I handle inconsistent files all the time and can't have it doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file with TextMate, select one `<CR>`, copy it. Open the "Find" dialogue with the "Regular Expression" option activated. Paste the `<CR>`, and replace them all with an empty string.